# Deploying a network of containers in a single K8s pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have an app running in an EC2 instance. It starts multiple containers on a network:

```
docker run --name purple \
    --net=treeOfPlums \
    --net-alias=purple \
    -d treeofplums/purple

docker run --name shiny \
    --net=treeOfPlums \
    --net-alias=shiny \
    -d treeofplums/shiny
```

In this case the containers `purple` and `shiny` can communicate because they are both on `treeOfPlums` with aliases `purple` and `shiny` respectively.

I want to deploy this app on K8s. I am using minikube for development. I do not want to use docker-in-docker here, where my main app is a container and it spins up the rest. Instead, I would like to make them all siblings.

**My question is, how do I specify the network name and container aliases on that network in a K8s pod?**

Using the keywords `network` and `network-alias` in the deployment yaml won't work. As I understand, containers in a single pod are on one network anyway, so setting an alias will be sufficient too. I am thinking of something like:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: purple
          image: purple
          network: treeOfPlums 
          net-alias: purple
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of pods is so that containers can talk as though they are on localhost. You don't need any additional network tweaks between containers in a pod.

From the docs:

> The applications in a pod all use the same network namespace (same IP
> and port space), and can thus “find” each other and communicate using
> localhost. Because of this, applications in a pod must coordinate
> their usage of ports. Each pod has an IP address in a flat shared
> networking space that has full communication with other physical
> computers and pods across the network.
>
> The hostname is set to the pod’s Name for the application containers
> within the pod.
>
> In addition to defining the application containers that
> run in the pod, the pod specifies a set of shared storage volumes.
> Volumes enable data to survive container restarts and to be shared
> among the applications within the pod.

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/#motivation-for-pods